# Is there any possibility to generate pdf using Spring 5 without using any tool out of the box?

Tags: spring, itext, export-to-pdf

Jasper report is using iText 2.1.7 for generating PDF and which is valunearability on security scan.

Is there any possibilty to generate pdf using Spring without using any other tool out of spring.

Comment: Can you not simply replace the version of iText with a safe version or replace the library itself with another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes: you could check the PDF spec and write code that outputs the appropriate bytes.

Practically no: the spec is complicated and real-life experience is required to know all the pitfalls. If it's not your primary business case you really don't want to spend that amount of time and money on creating a basic PDF writer.

iText is that tool for you. Maybe [OpenPDF (a fork of the iText code base before it was relicensed)](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF) could be an alternative.

Other workarounds are available such as using LibreOffice to create the PDFs for you.

But no matter what approach you pick, there's almost certainly some third-party software invovled.

Comment: can you please share the link of PDF spec

Comment: @DEBENDRADHINDA: I don't know which one you need, what the authoritative source on it is (it used to be Adobe, no idea if that's still true) and if any version I link to is freely available. But Google will be of immense help to you here.

Comment: The current pdf specification is ISO 32000-2:2020. Maybe for your purpose the old ISO 32000-1:2008 still suffices. Adobe provides a version without ISO headers, google for "PDF32000".